# LinqPad conversion error

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext, linqpad

i am getting an error on DuplicateOrder(TestOrder) as "cannot convert from tables.Order to int"  even though the OrderID in the Orders table is an int

```
        void DuplicateOrder(int orderId)
        {
                string methodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        try {
                using (MSBLegacyContext db = new MSBLegacyContext())
            {
                var TestOrder = db.Orders.Where(i=>i.OrderID == orderId).FirstOrDefault();
                DuplicateOrder(TestOrder);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
Console.WriteLine(methodName, ex, string.Format("Test", orderId));
        }}
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Notice that neither `Where` nor `FirstOrDefault` change the original type (collection of `tables.Order` will result in single (or null) instance of `tables.Order` being returned, hence you need to extract the `OrderId` property yourself.

Comment: Should it be `DuplicateOrder(TestOrder.OrderId);`

Comment: @Chad that's the part I don't get, that's a recursive call with no stopper.

Comment: Because your testOrder is of type Order and beware your method is recursive, would cause an infinite loop if there weren't an error.

Comment: This code strongly indicates that you're missing a method `DuplicateOrder` having a parameter of type `Order`. This code can't be intended to be recursive. So the question is: where's the missing method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root cause, the `FirstOrDefault` in below line will return the either first `order` object or null.

```
var TestOrder = db.Orders.Where(i=>i.OrderID == orderId).FirstOrDefault();
```

So type of `testOrder` is `order`, but the below method call is expecting the `int` parameter.

```
DuplicateOrder(TestOrder);
```

That's the reason yor are getting -

> cannot convert from tables.Order to int

To fix the issue, you need to add Select query in the Linq query and select the `int` column, something like below -

```
var TestOrder = db.Orders.Where(i=>i.OrderID == orderId).Select(s=> s.YourIntColumn).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit:**
After looking at you entire method and comments from others, you method call will definitely go to infinite loop. As you have not mentioned the purpose of this code, I am just assuming that you want to see whether a particular `orderid` is duplicate in the database or not. For that you can just use `Count` query and return the `Boolean` value. (not sure why do you have `void` in your method signature)

```
bool DuplicateOrder(int orderId) // changed from void to bool
{
  using (MSBLegacyContext db = new MSBLegacyContext())
  {
    return db.Orders.Where(i=>i.OrderID == orderId).Count()>1; // returns true if more than 1 order found   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have coded it correctly in your code, and if for a given orderId there were an Order, then your method would cause an infinite loop. Having said that, below is the correct way to get the int OrderId value:

```
using (MSBLegacyContext db = new MSBLegacyContext())
{
     var TestOrder = db.Orders
                    .FirstOrDefault(i=>i.OrderID == orderId);
     if (TestOrder != null)
     {
        var orderId = TestOrder.OrderId;
        // ...
     }
     // else whatever you would do
}
```

If OrderId is a primary key, then you would use SingleOrDefault() instead of FirstOrDefault(). The difference is, if there is more than 1 entry in the database with given orderId, SingleOrDefault() would throw an error - and in the case of primary keys that is what you want.